# Hosting website on local computer

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mobile

I am a web developer. I want to test how my website work on mobile and on pc.
I am using xampp and codeigniter.

I created a virtual server like: rssfeed.local. It works properly on my pc.
But I want that when I type above url in safari of my Ipod, It will also work.

So i change the ip of my pc to a static ip. 
Ex: 192.168.1.100 the ipod will understand and go to that website on my pc. But when i type rssfeed.local, the ipod does not understand.

Can you show me how to configure the apache for that purpose?

Comment: You need to somehow tell your iPood that rssfeed.local is actually 192.168.1.100... Not sure whether there's an easy way to edit hosts file in iPod

Comment: Just a suggestion. You can use Dynadns http://dyn.com/dns/. It will give a static hostname to your computer that can be used to access ur computer from any where even if you have a dynamic ip.

Answer (score 5):

You have 4 options here:

1. You would need to have a server, where you connect to with your iphone and your website and configure the DNS.
2. You need a router where you could configure DNS settings in, connect the internal ip address to a DNS.
3. Edit the hosts file on your iphone, and for that you would need to jailbreak it.
4. Use some software as a proxy tool, where the tool can translate the url to the internal ip address.

Answer (score -3):

you can try change your HOSTS file,
its location in the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc
add an item like "rssfeed.local 192.168.1.100" in the document below.
well,work done.